# How to add libgdx to an existing android studio project?

Tags: java, libgdx

My game is from scratch made without libgdx extensions, but now I want the libgdx extension so I can have box2d and some other extensions. What is the easiest and most effective way of importing that?

I know there are posts like this on stackoverflow, but I have massive problems importing libgdx. A detailed tutorial would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily integrate box2d and other extensions in libgdx.

Hopefully you're using gradle in your current libgdx project for dependency management.

put [box2d-dependency](https://libgdx.com/wiki/articles/dependency-management-with-gradle#box2d-gradle) in corresponding module and refresh gradle.

Other extensions 
https://libgdx.com/wiki/articles/dependency-management-with-gradle#libgdx-extensions